# How to open AIR3.2 For Android(.apk) Application from my Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, air

I've a flash game, which I've ported to Android using AIR3.2 for Android and I've created .apk and installed to my tablet and its playing fine.

Now I've created another Android application using Eclipse; Java; I want to open my above game from my this application..

I went through some examples but it didn't work for me.
The xml file generated after porting to AIR for Android is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.2">
  <id>com.animals.AnimalGame</id>
  <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
  <versionLabel>Animal Game</versionLabel>
  <filename>Animal Game</filename>
  <description/>
  <!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.<description><text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text></description>-->
  <name>Animal Game</name>
  <!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.<name><text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text></name>-->
  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>AndroidGameLoader.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients></initialWindow>
  <icon>
    <image36x36>36X36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>48X48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>72X72.png</image72x72>
  </icon>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
  <supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>
</application>
```

I've tried in my Android app to launch the game as follows:
HomeActivity.Java

```
package com.sush.myApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Button btn1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
              {
                try
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.animals.AnimalGame");
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    startActivity(i);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Game Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

              }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

but it didn't work it always goes to catch statement.
Can any one help me out on how to open an Air for Android app from Android app...
Is there anything else I've to include inside my game's xml file?

the error:

```
11-07 10:15:38.581: W/System.err(2140): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 10:15:38.732: W/System.err(2140):     at com.sush.myApp.HomeActivity$1.onClick(HomeActivity.java:47)
11-07 10:15:38.732: W/System.err(2140):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-07 10:15:38.742: W/System.err(2140):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-07 10:15:38.742: W/System.err(2140):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-07 10:15:38.762: W/System.err(2140):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 10:15:38.792: W/System.err(2140):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 10:15:38.832: W/System.err(2140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-07 10:15:38.863: W/System.err(2140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 10:15:38.871: W/System.err(2140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-07 10:15:38.881: W/System.err(2140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-07 10:15:38.912: W/System.err(2140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-07 10:15:38.912: W/System.err(2140):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 10:15:39.051: D/dalvikvm(2140): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 116K, 8% free 2881K/3104K, paused 74ms, total 103ms
```

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace();` before the toast and post the logcat here.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick response... I'm getting NullPointerException

Comment: I've edited my question by adding e.printStackTrace(); and also added my logcat above.
@LawrenceChoy

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I'm getting NullPointerException

Comment: Give us more information. Show us the line 47 of `HomeActivity` and the related code of it.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy I've Added the entire code of `HomeActivity`

Comment: @Sush19 Please, what is line 47?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy the line 47 is `i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem and now I can open AIR for Android application from my Android app.
I just changed

```
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.animals.AnimalGame");
```

To

```
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("air.com.animals.AnimalGame");
```

Now its working fine..